# Derive the dimensionless Gibbs free energy equation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, dimensional-analysis

I'm having trouble deriving the Gibbs free energy equation:
$$ G = \sum_i n_i \left(g_i^0(T) + RT\ln P_i\right),$$
then,
$$\dfrac{G}{RT} = \sum_i n_i\left[\dfrac{g_i^0(T)}{RT} + \ln P + \ln\left(\dfrac{n_i}{N}\right)\right],$$
where $N$ is the total number of moles in the system, and $Pi/P =
ni/N$ (from one equation to another it's easy to understand how it got there).

I have already started from the first law of thermodynamics and also considering $dT = 0$, but I am having difficulties in reaching this final expression.

Comment: That is the ideal Gibbs free energy, composed just of the free energy of each constituent and the entropy of mixing.

Comment: Please (1) define your variables, (2) describe what system you’re modeling, and (3) specify what starting definition you’re relying on for the Gibbs free energy. Otherwise it’s just equation salad.

Comment: @Chemomechanics (1) $n_i$ is the number of moles, $g^0$ is temperature-dependent Gibbs free energies, $R$ the universal gas constant, $T$ is temperature and $P_i$ the partial pressure of species $i$. (2) A chemical equilibrium system. (3) The differential form $dG = VdP - SdT$

Comment: $g^0$ can't be an energy if it's multiplied by the number of moles to give an energy. Molar Gibbs free energy?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I think it might be why I'm struggling to derive this equation. It's exactly how it appears in the book I'm following and that's exactly what the author says about $g^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with the differential form

$$dG=-S\,dT+V\,dP+\sum_ig_i\,dn_i,$$

with Gibbs free energy $G$, entropy $S$, temperature $T$,  volume $V$, pressure $P$, chemical potential or partial molar Gibbs free energy $g_i$ for species $i$, and amount $n_i$ of species $i$.

Now assume ideal gases for a gas system ($P_iV=n_iRT$), or alternatively ideal-gas vapor at equilibrium above condensed matter. With no chemical interactions, the Gibbs free energy of any one component can depend only on that component. At any particular temperature ($dT=0$) for a closed system ($dn_i=0$), therefore, we have

$$dG_i=V\,dP_i=\frac{n_iRT}{P_i}dP_i=n_iRT\,d\ln P_i,$$

where $P_i$ is normalized by some reference pressure to make the logarithmic argument dimensionless.

Integrating, we have

$$G_i-G_{i}^\circ=n_iRT\ln P_i;$$

$$G_i=n_i\left(RT\ln P_i+g_i^\circ(T)\right),$$

where $G_i^\circ$ and $g_i^\circ(T)$ are respectively the total and molar Gibbs free energies of pure species $i$ at temperature $T$, set to be consistent with the reference pressure mentioned earlier. Summing over the independent components, we obtain

$$G=\sum_in_i\left(RT\ln P_i+g^{\circ}_i(T)\right).$$

This appears to match the desired equation, yes?